# Docker swarm does not distribute the container in the cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a two servers to use in a Docker cluster Swarm(test only), one is a Manager and other is a Worker, but running the command `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml teste2` all the services is run in the manager and the worker not receive the containers to run, for some reason the Swarm is not achieving distributing the services in the cluster and running all in manager server.

Will my docker-compose.yml be causing the problem or might it be a network problem?

Here are some settings:

- Servers CentOs 7, Docker version 18.09.4;
- I executed the commands `systemctl stop firewalld && systemctl disable firewalld` to disable firewall;
- I executed the command `docker swarm join --token ...` in the worker;
- Result `docker node ls`:

  ```
  ID                            HOSTNAME               STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
  993dko0vu6vlxjc0pyecrjeh0 *   name.server.manager    Ready               Active              Leader              18.09.4
  2fn36s94wjnu3nei75ymeuitr     name.server.worker     Ready               Active                                  18.09.4
  ```
- File docker-compose.yml:

  ```
  version: "3"
  services:
    web:
          image: testehello
          deploy:
            replicas: 5
            update_config:
                  parallelism: 2
                  delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                  condition: on-failure
            # placement:
                  # constraints: [node.role == worker]
          ports:
            - 4000:80
          networks:
            - webnet

    visualizer:
          image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
          ports:
            - 8080:8080
          stop_grace_period: 1m30s
          volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
          deploy:
            placement:
                  constraints: [node.role == manager]

  networks:
    webnet:
  ```
- I executed the command `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml teste2`

In the docker-compose.yml I commented the parameters **placement** and **constraints** because they did not work and did not start the containers on the servers, without it the containers are started in the manager. Through the Visualizer all appear in the manager.

Comment: Try to add "mode: replicated" to section deploy

Comment: I add `mode: replicated` but did not distributed. Is there anything else to try?

Comment: Should work, i use 3.2 syntax, will provide an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the images are not accessible from a worker node, that is why they not receive containers, try to use this guide by docker https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

P.S. I think you solved it already, but just in case.